# RStudio not launching in xfce (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: xfce, remote-desktop, rstudio, x11rdp

Even after installing everything and getting the RStudio icon in the 'Development' section of x11 xfce Remote Desktop, the RStudio is not launching. It has no error, yet it is not launching. How to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the terminal and run the following command:

```
QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext rstudio
```

This worked for me. Inspiration: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3382#issuecomment-416659732.

Comment: I have been suggested to change the above command to '... studio' instead of the current '... rstudio'. Changing didn't work for me; check for yourself if it does.